# Signal handling in Pylons

Tags: python, pylons, signals

I have a pylons project where I need to update some in-memory structures periodically. This should be done on-demand. I decided to come up with a signal handler for this. User sends `SIGUSR1` to the main pylons thread and it is handled by the project.

This works except after handling the signal, the server crashes with following exception:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 264, in handle_request
   fd_sets = select.select([self], [], [], timeout)
select.error: (4, 'Interrupted system call')
```

Is it possible to fix this?

TIA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but not easy using the stock Python libraries. This is due to Python translating all OS errors to exceptions. However, EINTR should really cause a retry of the system call used.  Whenever you start using signals in Python you will see this error sporadically.

I have [code that fixes this](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/aid/pycopia/socket.py) (SafeSocket), by forking Python modules and adding that functionality. But it needs to be added everywhere system calls are used. So it's possible, but not easy. But you can use my open-source code, it may save you years of work. ;-)

The basic pattern is this (implemented as a system call decorator):

```
# decorator to make system call methods safe from EINTR
def systemcall(meth):
    # have to import this way to avoid a circular import
    from _socket import error as SocketError
    def systemcallmeth(*args, **kwargs):
        while 1:
            try:
                    rv = meth(*args, **kwargs)
            except EnvironmentError as why:
                if why.args and why.args[0] == EINTR:
                    continue
                else:
                    raise
            except SocketError as why:
                if why.args and why.args[0] == EINTR:
                    continue
                else:
                    raise
            else:
                break
        return rv
    return systemcallmeth
```

You could also just use that around your select call.

Comment: Just for reference, here is the (still open) Python ticket asking for retry on EINTR: http://bugs.python.org/issue9867

Answer (score 2):

A fix, at least works for me, from an [12 year old python-dev list post](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2000-October/009671.html)

```
    while True:
        try:
            readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, outputs, inputs, timeout)
        except select.error, v:
            if v[0] != errno.EINTR: raise
        else: break
```

The details of the actual select line isn't important... your "fd_sets = select.select([self], [], [], timeout)" line should work exactly the same.

The important bit is to check for EINTR and retry/loop if that is caught.
Oh, and don't forget to import errno.