# django Interrupted system call with tutorial app

Tags: python, django, system, call

I keep receiving this intermittent error even with just the poll application. My application is fairly simple, where at least for the moment, it is just serving up a small csv file via JSON to a jquery table. Both the traceback and my system configuration is listed below. Thanks in advance!

## Code

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "manage.py", line 14, in 
>       execute_manager(settings)
>     File "/home/baldig/shared_libraries/centos64/pkgs/python/2.6.5/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 459, in execute_manager
>       utility.execute()
>     File "/home/baldig/shared_libraries/centos64/pkgs/python/2.6.5/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 382, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
>     File "/home/baldig/shared_libraries/centos64/pkgs/python/2.6.5/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **options.**dict**)
>     File "/home/baldig/shared_libraries/centos64/pkgs/python/2.6.5/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)
>     File "/home/baldig/shared_libraries/centos64/pkgs/python/2.6.5/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 69, in handle
>       self.run(*args, **options)
>     File "/home/baldig/shared_libraries/centos64/pkgs/python/2.6.5/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 80, in run
>       self.inner_run(*args, **options)
>     File "/home/baldig/shared_libraries/centos64/pkgs/python/2.6.5/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 111, in inner_run
>       ipv6=self.use_ipv6, threading=threading)
>     File "/home/baldig/shared_libraries/centos64/pkgs/python/2.6.5/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 253, in run
>       httpd.serve_forever()
>     File "/home/baldig/shared_libraries/centos64/pkgs/python/2.6.5/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 224, in serve_forever
>       r, w, e = select.select([self], [], [], poll_interval)
>   select.error: (4, 'Interrupted system call')

## Config #

Django version 1.4.1
Python 2.6.5
CentOS 6
Intel Xeon E5630
64GB RAM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633067/signal-handling-in-pylons) with the same error for SocketServer.py, `'Interrupted system call'` .

Comment: Thanks! The solution seems a little "hacky" to me. The production code is actually served up via apache WSGI, so it's much more stable and I don't run into this problem.